# MSBuild: asterisks and strange ItemGroup Exclude behaviour

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuild-propertygroup

I have a script that attempts to construct an `ItemGroup` out of all files in a certain directory while excluding files with certain names (regardless of extension).

The list of files to be excluded initially contains file extensions, and I am using Community Tasks' `RegexReplace` to replace the extensions with an asterisk. I then use this list in the item's `Exclude` attribute. For some reason the files do not get excluded properly, even though the list appears to be correct.

To try and find the cause I created a test script (below) which has two tasks: first one initialises two properties with the list of file patterns in **two different ways**. The second task prints both properties and the files resulting from using both these properties in the `Exclude` attribute.

The properties' values appear to be identical, however the resulting groups are different. How is this possible?

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         DefaultTargets="Init;Test" ToolsVersion="3.5">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <Target Name="Init">
    <ItemGroup>
      <OriginalFilenames Include="TestDir\SampleProj.exe"/>
      <OriginalFilenames Include="TestDir\SampleLib1.dll"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <RegexReplace Input="@(OriginalFilenames)" Expression="\.\w+$" Replacement=".*">
      <Output TaskParameter="Output" ItemName="PatternedFilenames"/>
    </RegexReplace>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ExcludeFilesA>TestDir\SampleProj.*;TestDir\SampleLib1.*</ExcludeFilesA>
      <ExcludeFilesB>@(PatternedFilenames)</ExcludeFilesB>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Test">
    <Message Text='ExcludeFilesA: $(ExcludeFilesA)' />
    <Message Text='ExcludeFilesB: $(ExcludeFilesB)' />
    <ItemGroup>
      <AllFiles Include="TestDir\**"/>
      <RemainingFilesA Include="TestDir\**" Exclude="$(ExcludeFilesA)"/>
      <RemainingFilesB Include="TestDir\**" Exclude="$(ExcludeFilesB)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="&#xA;**AllFiles**&#xA;@(AllFiles, '&#xA;')" />
    <Message Text="&#xA;**PatternedFilenames**&#xA;@(PatternedFilenames, '&#xA;')" />
    <Message Text="&#xA;**RemainingFilesA**&#xA;@(RemainingFilesA, '&#xA;')" />
    <Message Text="&#xA;**RemainingFilesB**&#xA;@(RemainingFilesB, '&#xA;')" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Output (reformatted somewhat for clarity):

```
ExcludeFilesA: TestDir\SampleProj.*;TestDir\SampleLib1.*
ExcludeFilesB: TestDir\SampleProj.*;TestDir\SampleLib1.*

AllFiles:
  TestDir\SampleLib1.dll
  TestDir\SampleLib1.pdb
  TestDir\SampleLib2.dll
  TestDir\SampleLib2.pdb
  TestDir\SampleProj.exe
  TestDir\SampleProj.pdb

PatternedFilenames:
  TestDir\SampleProj.*
  TestDir\SampleLib1.*

RemainingFilesA:
  TestDir\SampleLib2.dll
  TestDir\SampleLib2.pdb

RemainingFilesB:
  TestDir\SampleLib1.dll
  TestDir\SampleLib1.pdb
  TestDir\SampleLib2.dll
  TestDir\SampleLib2.pdb
  TestDir\SampleProj.exe
  TestDir\SampleProj.pdb
```

Observe that both `ExcludeFilesA` and `ExcludeFilesB` look identical, but the resulting groups `RemainingFilesA` and `RemainingFilesB` differ.

Ultimately I want to obtain the list `RemainingFilesA` using the pattern generated the same way `ExcludeFilesB` is generated. Can you suggest a way, or do I have to completely rethink my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true cause of this was revealed accidentally when a custom task threw an exception.

The actual value of `ExcludeFilesA` is `TestDir\SampleProj.*;TestDir\SampleLib1.*` like one might expect. However the actual value of `ExcludeFilesB` is `TestDir\SampleProj.%2a;TestDir\SampleLib1.%2a`.

Presumably `Message` unescapes the string before using it, but `Include` and `Exclude` do not. That would explain why the strings look the same but behave differently.

Incidentally, the execution order doesn't seem to have anything to do with this, and I'm pretty sure (following extensive experimentation) that everything gets executed and evaluated exactly in the order in which it appears in this script.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to actually escape the asterisk in a `<FooItem Include="bar*baz" />` to later get it verbatim without file globbing, and I could not find any information on that. Your research helped me - using `%2a` turned off expansion and all `@->` transformations in later command got the asterisk.

Comment: aand immediately after writing this comment, I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/special-characters-to-escape where it is explicitely pointed out for Include and asterisk, d'oh.

Answer (score 0):

ItemGroups need to be evaluated before targets execution, and the `PatternedFilenames` ItemGroup is being created on the fly within its target container.
You could workaround this using the [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx) task, which will ensure the `PatternedFilenames` scope throughout the execution:

```
<RegexReplace Input="@(OriginalFilenames)" Expression="\.\w+$" Replacement=".*">
  <Output TaskParameter="Output" ItemName="PatternedFilenames_tmp"/>
</RegexReplace>
<CreateItem Include="@(PatternedFilenames_tmp)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="PatternedFilenames"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Comment: Oh... thanks for the workaround, I will try that. Could you possibly explain the order in which things occur in more detail please? Clearly `ExcludeFilesA` is initialised before the ItemGroup `RemainingFilesA` is created; how come the same doesn't happen for `RemainingFilesB`? It almost looks like the order is: 1. "Init" finishes; 2. ItemGroups from "Test" evaluated; 3. RegexReplace evaluated; 4. "Test" begins and prints messages. But surely that can't be so?...

Comment: Read "Property and Item Evaluation Order" section here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997067(VS.100).aspx
This post is related to your issue:
http://elegantcode.com/2006/12/11/msbuild-items-run-time-evaluation-behavior/